# confusion over atomic value vs node in xpath

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

(and how to avoid it without doing somersaults)
(saxon PE 11.4)

consider

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="('a','b','D')">
                <string>
                    <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>
                </string>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

against any input (I can never work out to use an initial template and make it work in oxygen)

so input is...

```
<root/>
```

it outputs

```
<root>
   <string>A</string>
   <string>B</string>
   <string>D</string>
</root>
```

(the actual outputting of this is just an illustration, this isnt the end goal)

What I'm trying to do is create an xpath expression that does the upper-case all in 1 expression and I get a sequence of upper case strings

so...1st guess

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="('a','b','D')/upper-case(.)">
                <string>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </string>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

naively this seems reasonable, I'm simply applying uppercase to each 'string' in the sequence, and using '/' as a pipe operator

but it complains

```
The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(). The supplied value is an atomic value
```

ah..so '/' wants the 'input' to be 'node()'s...how can i do this? preferably in the same expressions...i.e. it psuedo xpath

```
to-node(('a','b','D'))/upper-case(.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to apply the function to each item in the sequence with `!` e.g. `('a','b','D') ! upper-case(.)`.

Of course this simply converts the sequence of string items in a sequence of upper case string items, it doesn't construct nodes.

In XPath 4.0 https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xquery-40/xpath-40-diff.html#id-arrow-operator you will probably be able to use `('a','b','D') =!> upper-case()` as well.